# getting title field from the process array in the webform

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-webform

I am using the webform module for Drupal.

I needed to customize one of the webform nodes.

So I tried printing `[title] => title of this webform goes here!!!` using `<?php print drupal_render($form['process']['title']); ?>`

But it returns nothing, what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

FYI, the form can be rendered with; `drupal_render($form['submitted']);`

```
Array ( [#attached] => Array ( [css] => Array ( [0] => sites/all/modules/webform/css/webform.css ) [js] => Array ( [0] => sites/all/modules/webform/js/webform.js ) ) [#process] => Array ( [0] => webform_client_form_includes ) [#node] => stdClass Object ( [vid] => 22 [uid] => 2 [title] => title of this webform goes here!!! [log] => [status] => 1 [comment] => 1 [promote] => 1 [sticky] => 0 [nid] => 22 [type] => webform [language] => en [created] => 1373585579 [changed] => 1374117294 [tnid] => 0 [translate] => 0 [revision_timestamp] => 1374117294 [revision_uid] => 8 [body] => Array ( ) [rdf_mapping] => Array ( [rdftype] => ...
```

Comment: check this $form['#attached']['title']

Comment: @gayan I tried it before, nope...

Comment: so what about $form['#attached']['#process']['#node']['title']

Comment: @gayan you can't access objects with array notations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this,

```
echo $form[#node]->title;
var_dump($form[#node]);// to test it your node data
```

As from your `array`

```
Array ( 
     [#attached] => Array ([css] => Array ( [0] => sites/all/modules/webform/css/webform.css ) [js] => Array ( [0] =>   sites/all/modules/webform/js/webform.js ))
     [#process] => Array ( [0] => webform_client_form_includes ) 
     [#node] => stdClass Object ( [vid] => 22 [uid] => 2 [title] => title of this webform goes here!!! [log] => [status] => 1 [comment] => 1 [promote] => 1 [sticky] => 0 [nid] => 22 [type] => webform [language] => en [created] => 1373585579 [changed] => 1374117294 [tnid] => 0 [translate] => 0 [revision_timestamp] => 1374117294 [revision_uid] => 8 [body] => Array ( ) [rdf_mapping] => Array ( [rdftype] => ...
```